# Which angle is to be taken for small displacement in Simple Harmonic Motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

For above system I wrote the restoring torque on the body for a small angular displacement θ but I got confused as to which θ will be correct for finding time period. I took the following two possible angular displacements[image]

In 1st case I took the angle with mean position of string to displaced position of string and for 2nd case I took the angular displacement of cynlinder as seen from top . Both cases give different time period so how will be decide which of them is correct one?

Comment: The 1st one is correct. The net force acting on the tube is whatever component of gravity is perpendicular to the string since it can't be canceled by the tension. This restoring force depends on the angle that the string makes with the vertical ($\mathbf F = -mg\sin\theta\hat\theta$) so this angle is the one relevant to calculating the period.

Comment: Either coordinate can be used as a generalized coordinate; in either case the configuration manifold is 1-dimensional. If the Lagrangian is formulated properly, in either case the period will be the same, because the physics does not depend on frame of reference.

Comment: You can use either the angle (call it ) in your left hand diagram, or angle  in the right hand diagram as, for small , =. My preference is to use  in the equation of motion, which we can write as $G=I\ddot \theta$, in which  is the moment of inertia of the cylinder about its central axis and  is the torque on it from the strings – for which it's up to you to find an expression!